# Why can't uvcdynctrl see my webcam?

Tags: camera

I have added a Creative Labs Live! Optia webcam to my Debian Squeeze machine and can see it using `lsusb`.

Unfortunately, when I use `uvcdynctrl -l` I get the message `No Devices Found`

I am on Kernel version 2.6.32 which I understand contains the uvc drivers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just because the kernel has the source for a driver doesn't mean that driver was included in the build. First try `lsmod | grep uvc` to see if the uvc module is currently loaded, if not try `modinfo uvc` to see if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your kernel contains UVC but have you build them (or creators of Debian)? You should check module as Kevin wrote, next driver may be compiled in the kernel, so check config: `grep USB_VIDEO_CLASS /usr/src/linux/.config`. When you'll have driver running, some webcams needs firmware at least.